# Regular expression meaning in R : "( \n|\n )"

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe

I am new to R programming and was trying out the gsub function for text replacement in pandas dataframe series(i.e new_text).

It a vast series so will not be able to print all here.
It is just a series with strings containing postal address.

I came across this gsub code : `gsub(pattern = "( \n|\n )", replacement = " ", x = new_text) -> new_text`

can you please let me know the meaning of this regex expression as well as the python alternative using regex expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern, slightly rewritten, is `[ ]\n|\n[ ]`, which says to match:

```regex
[ ]\n  a space followed by a newline
|      OR
\n[ ]  a newline followed by a space
```

Note that you *might* be able to use `[ ]?\n[ ]?` to the same effect, depending on the actual text you are using with `gsub`.